# Sort a range in a shared Google sheet without temporary filter view

Tags: google-sheets

When I sort a range on a Google sheet, it sorts just fine.  When a collaborator who has edit access attempts to perform the exact same action, a Temporary Filter View is produced.  When she closes the Temporary Filter View, the sheet returns to its previous state - unsorted.

How can a collaborator with edit access to a Google sheet sort the data on that sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with protected ranges (in the toolbar under View > Protected Ranges). One of the columns was considered a protected range, and so any sorting was considered a temporary filter. Removing the protected status solved the issue.

Source: Works with OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

- Use the  menu commands
- Use contextual commands (right click)
- Use a "regular filter"

For details, see [Sort and Filter your Data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en)

Comment: Following the instructions on the page to which you linked results in a Temporary Filter View when my collaborator tries to sort.  My question is how to sort a range without producing the Temporary Filter View.